# Activity Monitor is unuseable because it's freezing mouse cursor when launched

Tags: mouse, performance, activity-monitor

A weird problem started happening on my system in recent days (can't remember exactly). When I launch Activity Monitor, mouse pointer freezes and can't move normally until I kill Activity Monitor by using keyboard.
It works OK otherwise.

OS X version is `10.11.6 (15G1108)`. I have also installed SmoothMouse.

#### EDIT:

I removed SmoothMouse by issuing command `brew cask zap smoothmouse`, now the mouse cursor can move while Activity Monitor is opened, but Activity Monitor itself is still freezing and is barely usable.

Comment: Given that SmoothMouse is known to have compatibility issues with some application by the developer's own admission, have you tried disabling or removing it to test if its the cause of the issue?

Comment: I'm going to test it & update the question shortly.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan done, updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away after I rebooted the system. (It was running for several weeks without rebooting before).

This clearly indicates that OS X just can't handle long uptime, because Apple cares more about bells and whistles than stability. :(